# ¿Cómo puedo implementar algunos botones a una webview que me permitan navegar hacia atrás y adelante?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview-android

He construido un `Activity` y le he implementado una `WebView`, el detalle es que al pulsar el botón atrás de mi sistema me saca del `Activity`, quisiera implementar alguna función que me de acceso a tener algunos botones para ir a la página anterior o a la siguiente, el código que he implementado es:

```
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Agregué una respuesta, se recomienda validar canGoForward() y canGoBack()  para saber si se puede permitir la acción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes hacer algo así:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

basicamente es sobreescribir el metodo onBackPressed de la actividad.

saludos

Comment: y para adelante?

Comment: puedes usar goForward()

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos que permiten la navegación en un `WebView` son, hacia adelante es

**[goForward()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#goForward())**

hacia atras

**[goBack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#goForward())**

Pero para llamarlos se recomienda validar si estas acciones se pueden realizar mediante **[canGoForward()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canGoForward())** y **[canGoBack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canGoBack())** respectivamente.

Puedes realizar un método el cual determine que tipo de acción deseas realizar:

```
private static final int BACK = 0, FORWARD = 1;

      private void executeAction(int index){
            switch(index){
                case BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack()){
                        webView.goBack();
                    }
                    break;
                case FORWARD:
                    if(webView.canGoForward()){
                        webView.goForward();
                    }   
                    break;
                   default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

el método anterior lo puedes llamar desde un botón, si deseas ir hacia adelante:

```
executeAction(FORWARD);
```

o hacia atrás

```
executeAction(BACK);
```